# The implementation of the MapFunction is not serializable Flink

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to implement a class that enables the user to manipulate N input Streams without having constraints on Types of input Streams.

For starter, I wanted to transform all input DataStreams into keyedStreams.
So, I mapped the input dataStream into a Tuple and after that, I applied KeyBy to convert it into keystream.

I always get a problem of serialization, I tried to follow this guide https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/java_lambdas.html and it didn't work.

What I do like to know is :

1. What is Serialization/Deserialization in Java ? and what is used for.
2. What are the problems that I can counter in Flink with Serialization
3. What is the problem in my code( you may find below the code and the error message)

Thank you very much.

**Main Class:**

```
public class CEP {

private  Integer streamsIdComp = 0;
final  private Map<Integer, DataStream<?> > dataStreams = new HashMap<>();
final  private Map<Integer, TypeInformation<?>> dataStreamsTypes = new HashMap<>();

public <T> KeyedStream<Tuple2<Integer, T>, Integer> converttoKeyedStream(DataStream<T> inputStream){

    Preconditions.checkNotNull(inputStream, "dataStream");
    TypeInformation<T> streamType = inputStream.getType();

    KeyedStream<Tuple2<Integer,T>,Integer> keyedInputStream = inputStream.
            map(new MapFunction<T, Tuple2<Integer,T>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Integer, T> map(T value) throws Exception {
                    return Tuple2.of(streamsIdComp, value);
                }
            }).
            keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<Integer, T>, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer getKey(Tuple2<Integer, T> integerTTuple2) throws Exception {
                    return integerTTuple2.f0;
                }
            });
    return keyedInputStream;
}

public <T1> void addInputStream(DataStream<T1> inputStream) {

    TypeInformation<T1> streamType = inputStream.getType();

    dataStreamsTypes.put(streamsIdComp, streamType);
    dataStreams.put(streamsIdComp, this.converttoKeyedStream(inputStream));
    streamsIdComp++;
}
}
```

**Test Class**

```
public class CEPTest {

@Test
public void addInputStreamTest() throws Exception {
    //test if we can change keys in a keyedStream
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<Record> input1 = env.fromElements(
            new Record("1", 1, "a"),
            new Record("2", 2, "b"),
            new Record("3", 3, "c"))
            .keyBy(Record::getBizName);

    DataStream<Integer> input2 = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4);

    CEP cepObject = new CEP();
    cepObject.addInputStream(input1);
    cepObject.addInputStream(input2);

   }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the MapFunction 
is not serializable. The implementation accesses fields of its enclosing class, which is a 
common reason for non-serializability. A common solution is to make the function a proper 
(non-inner) class, or a static inner class.

at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:151)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:71)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1821)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:188)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.map(DataStream.java:590)
at CEP.converttoKeyedStream(CEP.java:25)
at CEP.addInputStream(CEP.java:45)
at CEPTest.addInputStreamTest(CEPTest.java:33)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at 
com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: CEP
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:586)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:133)
... 29 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flink is a distributed framework. That means, your program is potentially going to run on a thousands of nodes. This also means that each worker node has to receive code to be executed along with the required context. Simplifying a bit, both events flowing through the system and functions to be executed have to be serializable - as they are transfer via the wire. This is why serialization is important in distributed programming in general.

---

In short, serialization is a process of encoding data into byte representation that can be transferred and restored on another node (another JVM).

---

Back to the problem. Here is your cause:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: CEP
```

which is caused by line

```
return Tuple2.of(streamsIdComp, value);
```

You are using `streamsIdComp` variable which is a field in `CEP` class. That means, Flink has to serialize whole class to be able to access this field when executing `MapFunction`. You can overcome it by introducing local variable in `converttoKeyedStream` function:

```
public <T> KeyedStream<Tuple2<Integer, T>, Integer> converttoKeyedStream(DataStream<T> inputStream){

    Preconditions.checkNotNull(inputStream, "dataStream");
    TypeInformation<T> streamType = inputStream.getType();
    // note this variable is local
    int localStreamsIdComp = streamsIdComp;

    KeyedStream<Tuple2<Integer,T>,Integer> keyedInputStream = inputStream.
            map(new MapFunction<T, Tuple2<Integer,T>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Integer, T> map(T value) throws Exception {
                    // and is used here
                    return Tuple2.of(localStreamsIdComp, value);
                }
            }).
            keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<Integer, T>, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer getKey(Tuple2<Integer, T> integerTTuple2) throws Exception {
                    return integerTTuple2.f0;
                }
            });
    return keyedInputStream;
}
```

that way Flink has to serialize just this single variable, not the whole class itself.